# 'between two adjacent trees' or 'between two consecutive trees'?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is better?

A third choice is 'between two neighboring trees'

Here the trees are on a straight line.

Comment: *Consecutive* refers to ordering (first, second, third, etc.). I wouldn't use it without specific context.

Comment: What kind of "tree"? A green one with leaves and bird nests growing in the forest? Or planted along a boulevard or the driveway of a meticulously maintained estate?

Comment: *Any* two trees are on a straight line (if they're on a plane) so it takes more than two of them to establish a context where **consecutive** would apply.

Comment: I will remove my downvote when additional context is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have in mind anything highly specific, "adjacent" and "neighboring" would be better than "consecutive".

Of course, it would have been better to know your full sentence before providing advice.

[image]